# Append jquery tooltip inside td

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip

I have this table markup

```
<tr class="row0">
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_sistemazione">A4 + CAR</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_destinazione">Ancona-Igoumenitsa</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_datetime">2019-08-13</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_time">13:30</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_stagione">Bassa</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_optiondate">2019-07-25</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_issued">no</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_appunti">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST VERY VER LOOOONG TEST</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-name">wassy</td>
</tr>
```

I want the td-input_appunti field text that is very long to be truncated and showed inside a tooltip on hover.
To truncate I used the following css

```
<style>
.td-input_appunti {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 90px;
}
</style>
```

to show the tooltip I used the following jquery

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".td-input_appunti", function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$this.attr('title')) {
         $this.tooltip({
             title: $this.text(),
         });
     $this.tooltip('show');
     }
 });
 });
</script>
```

problem is that in this way the tooltip appears as a div next the td with class .td-input_appunti and I want this to be inside the td tags, cause if is outside will breacks the next td position. I cannot change the td markup to select a more specific tag inside td, cause the table is generated through a plugin, so this must be done with jquery.

**EXPECTED**

```
<tr class="row0">
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_sistemazione">A4 + CAR</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_destinazione">Ancona-Igoumenitsa</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_datetime">2019-08-13</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_time">13:30</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_stagione">Bassa</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_optiondate">2019-07-25</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_issued">no</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_appunti">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST VERY VER LOOOONG TEST
<div class="tooltip fade top in" style="top: 372px; left: 946.5px; display: block;">
<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST VERY VER LOOOONG TEST</div>
</div>
</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-name">wassy</td>
</tr>
```

**OBTAINED**

```
<tr class="row0">
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_sistemazione">A4 + CAR</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_destinazione">Ancona-Igoumenitsa</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_datetime">2019-08-13</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_time">13:30</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_stagione">Bassa</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_optiondate">2019-07-25</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_issued">no</td>
<td width="7%" class="center td-input_appunti">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST VERY VER LOOOONG TEST</td>
<div class="tooltip fade top in" style="top: 372px; left: 946.5px; display: block;">
<div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST VERY VER LOOOONG TEST</div>
</div>
<td width="7%" class="center td-name">wassy</td>
</tr>
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

fixed in this way

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$( ".td-input_appunti" ).wrapInner( '<span class="tooltipfix"></span>');
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".td-input_appunti", function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$this.attr('title')) {
         $(".tooltipfix").tooltip({
             title: $this.text(),
             position: { my: "bottom" }
         });
     }
 });
 });
</script>
```